# How to install npm package when the server is running?

Tags: npm

I have started a local server and everything is doing fine. However, when I tried to install a new package in the terminal, I couldn't get it to work. I am new to work with the terminal, it will be great if someone can tell me what to do in this case.

[image: Started local server]

[image: Tried to run command line]

Comment: So are you trying to install npm on ubuntu server.?

Comment: It's a mac server. I have installed npm and have started a local server. I am trying to install a package called GeoJson-flip. But whatever I typed in the terminal doesn't see to work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Open the Terminal app** and type `brew install node`

**Sit back and wait**. **Homebrew** downloads some files and installs them. And that’s it.

To make sure you have Node and NPM installed, run two simple commands to see what version of each is installed:

To see if Node is installed, type `node -v` in Terminal. This should print the version number so you’ll see something like this `v0.10.31`

To see if **NPM** is installed, type `npm -v` in Terminal. This should print the version number so you’ll see something like this `1.4.27`